# New-SCWebDeployPackage is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to package a Sitecore solution and followed the instructions mentioned in the following URLs.

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit?roles=developer

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure/configuring_sitecore_azure/package_a_sitecore_solution_for_the_azure_app_service?roles=developer

I have PowerShell (5.0). I have also updated Azure PowerShell Module 3.1.0

When I run the command `Start-SitecoreAzurePackaging` with all the options specified in the Sitecore documentation, I get the following error.

> The term 'New-SCWebDeployPackage' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you done Import-Module Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets?

Comment: Yes.. Did that too! "Import-Module Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets" ran successfully..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'New-SCWebDeployPackage' cmdlet will be available after importing assembly **Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll**

By default, loading an assembly from a network path in PowerShell console is disabled, It can be enabled by creating two PowerShell configuration files:

- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

Open new PowerShell console window and import module:

```ps
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll"
```

Answer (score 3):

This helped me when i was getting this issue...

> If you downloaded the Sitecore Azure Toolkit as a .ZIP and unzip it,
>   the individual files will be marked as "blocked" files. if they are all blocked your Powershell script wont work.
>
> Before unzipping, right click the zip file, go to security and select the Unblock button on the .ZIP file, then extract.

once i did this it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. Probably it has to do with your scriptroot: in the psm1 that you imported, there is a line that loads the assembly with some more cmdlets, one them being the New-SCWebDeployPackage:

```ps
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.dll"
```

you could try to manually import that module.

Comment: We even tried that but with no luck. Were you able to deploy the solution successfully?