# Packaging a Sitecore 9 solution with the Sitecore Azure Toolkit

Tags: azure, paas

I have a Sitecore 9 instance that I'd like to deploy on Azure PaaS. I'm following the instructions here:

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit/overview/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit

I've been trying to package the solution with the Sitecore Azure Toolkit, and I'm currently stuck trying to run Start-SitecoreAzurePackaging.  I'm getting the error pasted below.

I've tried the solutions from the following pages with no success:

[New-SCWebDeployPackage is not recognized](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/new-scwebdeploypackage-is-not-recognized)

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/019579

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

Thanks!

> PS C:\sat> Start-SitecoreAzurePackaging
>
> cmdlet Start-SitecoreAzurePackaging at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters: SitecorePath:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myTest DestinationFolderPath: C:\sat\wem
>   CargoPayloadFolderPath: C:\sat\resources\9.0.0\CargoPayloads
>   CommonConfigPath:
>   C:\sat\resources\9.0.0\Configs\Common.Packaging.config.json
>   SkuConfigPath:
>   C:\sat\resources\9.0.0\Configs\XPSingle.Packaging.config.json
>   ParameterXmlPath: C:\sat\resources\9.0.0\MsDeployXmls Connecting to
>   database 'myTest_Core' on server '.'. Extracting schema Extracting
>   schema from database
>
> **New-SCWebDeployPackage : Connecting to database 'myTest_Core' on server '.'. Extracting schema Extracting schema from database At
>   C:\sat\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:190 char:45
>   + ... ckagePath = New-SCWebDeployPackage -Path $SitecorePath -Destination $ ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Connecting to d...a from database:String) [New-SCWebDeployPackage], Excep    tion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId,Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.NewSCWebDeployPackage**
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs0a610797-07eb-441a
>   -b4be-a53164a522d1\Sitecore.core.dacpac'. File name: 'C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs0a610797-07eb-441a-b4be-a53164a522d1\Sitecore.core.dacpac'
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShar e share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolea n useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) 
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileO ptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Package.Common.FileSystemProvider.ReadFile(String
>   fileName)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.DatabasePackager.PackageDatabases(XDocument
>   connStringFile)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.Build(SitecoreInstallationFolderTree
>   scInstFold Tree, DirPath outputDir, String targetFileName, Boolean
>   force, String version)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.NewSCWebDeployPackage.ProcessRecord()
>
> **New-SCWebDeployPackage : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs0a610797-07eb-441a-b4be-a53164a522d1\Sitecore.core.dacpac'.
>   File name:
>   'C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs0a610797-07eb-441a-b4be-a53164a522d1\Sitecore.core.dacpac'
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>
>   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>   at Sitecore.Cloud.Package.Common.FileSystemProvider.ReadFile(String
>   fileName)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.DatabasePackager.PackageDatabases(XDocument
>   connStringFile)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.Build(SitecoreInstallationFolderTree
>   scInstFoldTree, DirPath outputDir, String targetFileName, Boolean
>   force, String version)    at
>   Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.NewSCWebDeployPackage.ProcessRecord()
>   At C:\sat\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:190 char:45
>   + ... ckagePath = New-SCWebDeployPackage -Path $SitecorePath -Destination $ ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.IO.FileN...ProcessRecord():String) [New-SCWebDeployPackage],
>   Excep    tion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId,Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.NewSCWebDeployPackage**
>
> Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\avi\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs0a610797-07eb-441a-b4be-a53164a522d1\Sitecore.core.
>   dacpac'.

Comment: What version of SDK you use? Could you try the latest one- 2.0.3 from [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit/2x/Sitecore_Azure_Toolkit_203.aspx) ?

Answer (score 2):

When you install your solution with SIF, Sitecore will create user account to connect to the databases. My guess: there accounts don't have suffisiant permissions to generate dacpac's.

So what you could try is: swap over to the sa account in your connectionstrings for the sake of packaging your solution (or change the permissions of all created users by SIF)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Have you set integratedSecurity? The default value is false  - This means that the user ID and password from the connection strings in the \App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config file will be used.

Please check the App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config. the DB user should have sufficient permission.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to setup a Sitecore V9 PaaS infrastructure in Azure you could try using the Sitecore market place and using the wizard to install all the necessary resources for a 9 or 9.1 PaaS environment.

having used the ARM templates for setting up an 8.2 Azure instance my advice to you with regards to the errors you receive while executing them are the following...

1. Ensure all your URLs in your parameters.json file resolve correctly. ctrl + click each one and ensure that the scwdp zip file downloads and you dont get a 403
2. Ensure all your scwdp are from the exact sitecore topology. if your using 9 make sure they are all 9 or all 9.1, not a mixture of both
3. Set a complex SQL Server password in the parameters file so you dont get any "Password not complex enough errors"
4. Setup GIT in the folder where all your Sitecore deployment/ARM templates are stored. That way you have a history for when you make changes.

using ARM templates is not a simple process and it involves a lot of trial and error. Most of the errors don't indicate what the root cause is, but if you ensure my points above are correct it will work.

for more info see my Questions/Answers regarding the issues i experienced with ARM templates on this forum.